# Rails 3.2.1  - Could not find rake-0.9.2.2 in any of the sources - Locaweb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new in Rails and I'm getting some problems.
About system: Rails-3.2.1 Ruby-1.8.7 RedHat

Everything works well in local system. The problem occurs on web host.
I'm trying to configure the system, but the information given isnt good enough.
I'm using mysql (mysql2 gem) and the database.yml is configured properly (I guess).

**database.yml**

```
# MySQL.  Versions 4.1 and 5.0 are recommended.
# 
# Install the MYSQL driver
#   gem install mysql2
#
# Ensure the MySQL gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'mysql2'
#
# And be sure to use new-style password hashing:
#   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/old-client.html
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: rffaguiar
  pool: 5
  username: rffaguiar
  password: ******
  host: mysql01.rffaguiar.com.br

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: rffaguiar
  pool: 5
  username: rffaguiar
  password: ******
  host: mysql01.rffaguiar.com.br

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: rffaguiar
  pool: 5
  username: rffaguiar
  password: ******
  host: mysql01.rffaguiar.com.br
```

**bundle command**

```
/home/storage/3/d2/f5/rffaguiar/rails_apps/teste_pos$ bundle
Using rake (0.9.2.2) 
Using i18n (0.6.0) 
Using multi_json (1.0.4) 
Using activesupport (3.2.1) 
Using builder (3.0.0) 
Using activemodel (3.2.1) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using journey (1.0.1) 
Using rack (1.4.1) 
Using rack-cache (1.1) 
Using rack-test (0.6.1) 
Using hike (1.2.1) 
Using tilt (1.3.3) 
Using sprockets (2.1.2) 
Using actionpack (3.2.1) 
Using mime-types (1.17.2) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.10) 
Using mail (2.4.1) 
Using actionmailer (3.2.1) 
Using arel (3.0.0) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.31) 
Using activerecord (3.2.1) 
Using activeresource (3.2.1) 
Using bundler (1.0.21) 
Using coffee-script-source (1.2.0) 
Using execjs (1.3.0) 
Using coffee-script (2.2.0) 
Using rack-ssl (1.3.2) 
Using json (1.6.5) 
Using rdoc (3.12) 
Using thor (0.14.6) 
Using railties (3.2.1) 
Using coffee-rails (3.2.2) 
Using johnson (1.2.0) 
Using jquery-rails (2.0.0) 
Using mysql (2.8.1) 
Using mysql2 (0.3.11) 
Using rails (3.2.1) 
Using sass (3.1.14) 
Using sass-rails (3.2.4) 
Using uglifier (1.2.3) 
[32mYour bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.[0m
```

The test app has only 1 controller(hello), 1 view(index) and 1 model.
When the root is that default rails html page, it's ok, but when I modify the root to 'hello#index', I get 500 error page.

I don't know if theres something related, but when using 'rake test' i get this:

> Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'

But there's no mysql.sock there.
I've been searching for a couple hours about these problems without success.
Can anyone point me to the right direction? Sorry if theres something wrong, this is my first question here.

**Update 1:**

```
netstat -ln | grep mysql
```

Returns nothing.

**Update 2:**
Now, I'm getting a passenger error page:

> Could not find rake-0.9.2.2 in any of the sources
>   (Bundler::GemNotFound)

But the gem is on Gemfile.This is the [link](http://wiki.locaweb.com/pt-br/Criando_teste_com_rails_3) provided by my webhost to configure the test. Forget the portuguese, look at the code, =). There, you can see IP on host line, and not a hostname like I'm doing, but they say to use hostname because DB IP can change. Yes, I'm trying all the tests using both.

About the socket line: I used it only when I got the mysql error before. Now I removed it.

About passenger: I'm doing the tests after restarting passenger with restart.txt

Comment: You say "the database.yml is configured properly (I guess)" - why is that a guess? Where did you get that configuration from - especially the `socket` line?

Comment: mysql --version returns: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.54, for unknown-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Comment: @Gareth: I got database.yml from the webhost. I tested the socket line  after the error given in 'mysql.sock'. But i tested with and without it.

Comment: Is that the whole of your `database.yml`? Do you have a `production` section?

Comment: could you please give us the version of rake used by your host. It seems. Maybe you should run the "bundle" command too.

Comment: @djtal64 , bundle command is on question now.

Comment: I notice you're using the same database for all three environments, which is almost-certainly wrong; re-read the comment in the middle of `database.yml` - "Do not set this db to the same as development or production."

Comment: `mysql -h mysql01.rffaguiar.com.br -u rffaguiar -p rffaguiar`  <-- Can you run that and paste the output (you'll need to type your password)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for help, but the webhost answered me after days and days disturbing them.
They say (a brief summary):

> You're using rails 3.2.1 and this version doesn't have a good
>   performance in shared host. We did a test using rails 3.0.9 and worked
>   normally. Please rebuild your application again with 3.0.9.

I don't even need to say that I'll change webhost. They have a tutorial for rails 3.2.1 and it doesnt work. This is insane, worried me for 3 days. My webhost was Locaweb (BR).

Again, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It is looking for socket at the default path  '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'
If this is not where it exists you have to specify it explicitly in socket: parameter

To find out where the socket file is, you can do:

```
netstat -ln | grep mysql
```

Comment: Oh sorry, I did this, but forgot the last line 'socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'. Your command returns nothing here

Comment: so it means the mysql service/demon is not running. get it running first.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run:

```
$ mysqladmin variables
```

should spit out the socket location, if you have mysqladmin...

EDIT:

Starting to sound to me like Mysql isn't running. Try:

```
$ cd /etc/init.d
$ ./mysqld start
```

Or more simply:

```
$ /etc/init.d/mysqld start
```

Comment: did you use the put the './' in front of it?

Comment: Sorry, no. Now returns 'permission denied'.

Comment: then you need to use sudo first. like this: `sudo ./mysqld start` then type in your password when prompted, then you should be bumpin :)

Comment: Here's the message: "no tty present and no askpass program specified"

Comment: log out of your ssh session then ssh in again, but pass the -t option when you do like this: `ssh -t user@wherever.com` then do the command again (with sudo)

Comment: Matthew, I'm not in home, my linux notebook isnt here. I'm using a windows notebook right now and unfortunately I don't know how to pass ssh options (-t) in winSCP(ssh for windows). I'll do it in a few hours.

Comment: Remember that the database server might not be the same as the application server; the webhost might well have a MySQL cluster elsewhere that they expect customers to use.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're experiencing permission issues when trying to restart `mysqld`, **I'd recommend emailing your webhost and asking them what your `database.yml` file should look like if you wish to run a Rails project on their system.**

Chances are they've helped other customers solve this problem in the past.

If you receive an answer, I encourage you to add it to your question so other people using the same webhost will know how to resolve the database problem.

Comment: The problem is mysql isn't running, and he doesn't know what he's doing. Your suggestion will only solve one of these problems. Sometimes the only way to learn is to get your hands muddy :) I got his back...

Comment: Yeah, I opened a ticket and sent an email hours ago. I'm just waiting the morning to call them. And about 'chances are they have helped others', yes, probably. But their forum is offline right now.

Answer (score 0):

I think the socket line is no usefull here.
I you provide a host line AR should connect to this host instead of using unix socket

If you don't use socket in your mysql config remove this line.

**Update**

Other point do not use the same database for test/dev/prod envirnonment since test will erase the database before and after each tests it execute

Can you try running the following command :

```
bundle exec rake test
```

With it the exeact activated gem will be used instaed of the sytem one.

In general when deploying to your prod or other envirnonment

do a

```
bundle install command
```

before so it install all the new gem required by your app

Answer (score 0):

A little work with `dig` shows that [this page explains where to find your MySQL setup details](http://ajuda.locaweb.com.br/pt-br/Informa%C3%A7%C3%B5es_de_acesso_ao_banco_MySQL). This implies to me that your webhost keeps database-servers separate from application-servers, and so the problem is not "needing to start MySQL".

The solution is probably to remove the `socket` line from `database.yml`, and check that `host`, `username`, `password` and `database` are correct as per the link above; note that your production deployment will almost-certainly be looking for a `production` section, not the `development` section.

Comment: 1 - I'm trying all the tests with and without the socket line. At this moment, I removed it. 2- About mysql setup, this is the [link](http://wiki.locaweb.com/pt-br/Criando_teste_com_rails_3) provided by my webhost. The host line is given with IP, but they say to use the hostname because the DB IP can change. 3 - I put the same configuration on development, test and production. Probably the error is mine, but I don't know what.

Comment: Can you paste the whole of your `database.yml` into the question?

Comment: Yes. There is on question now.

Comment: I saw that and before used a different database, did tests and nothing. That link above about configuration have this line 'Nota: Você pode colocar o mesmo banco de dados para development, production e tests.', which means 'You can put the same database for development,production and test'. This is crazy. I got an email answer about them. See my answer. Thanks for your help, but don't spent your time here anymore, =).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using phpmyadmin on apache2 to see if MySQL will run and also to get at your
databases for inspection. Also it may help newer rails 3.2.1 to use newer ruby versions like 1.9. I've seen where posts say 1.8 has issues with rails 3.1.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

1) Have you specified a correct source in your Gemfile?

For example, you might have rubygems as a gem source in your local machine.
But for the server side, you might need to add 

`source :rubygems`

in your Gemfile

2) Check if you have excluded vendor/cache in your repo.
Try including these files.